# Is there anyway I can use Sandcastle in order to create .chm files from .xml file having Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express installed?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-express, chm, sandcastle, visual-web-developer-2010

I found a very nice documentation for creating .chm files from .xml files using Sandcastle : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/devdocs/thread/3a631356-638e-451e-816c-c60d459c3775 . The only problem is that after I managed to arrive almost at the end of the instalation process, I saw that it is required to have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2010 or 2012, but I have used Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express for my project. Is there anyway I can use Sandcastle in order to create .chm files from .xml file having Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express installed?

OR

Is there an alternative (free) to Sandcastle in order to obtain the .chm file without installing another version of VS ? I couldn't manage to find any other program that converts .xml files to .chm files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/). I assume when you say xml files you mean documentation within the source code. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: I would assume that XML means "out of source" help, not the in-source (comment) kind, with tags linking it to the source. If it were within the source, I assume he'd say he had source, not XML :-)

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, I will have a look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sandcastle comes with its own GUI for managing Sandcastle projects.

1. Install Sandcastle using the supplied installer

   - https://shfb.codeplex.com/
2. Click Start
3. Search for `Sandcastle` (I can't find it in the start menu)
4. Select `Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI`

The GUI that opens is exactly the same as the "Properties" editor displayed in Visual Studio.

From the `File` menu, you can either select to open an existing sandcastle project, or create a new one.

This is useful if you are creating documentation outside of Visual Studio (eg. How-to Manuals)